# OpenLDAP won't search more than 500 entries, even when using paged search

Tags: python, ldap, openldap

I'm setting up an OpenLDAP database, and I am currently testing how it handles adding lots of users. I wrote some test functions to add thousands of users, and I can manually check for individual users to see that yes they are being added to the database. However, when I try to use ldapsearch to get all of the users that are in the database:

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL -b dc=example,dc=com uidNumber
```

it stops after printing out 500 and then spits out

```
Size limit exceeded (4)
```

I've tried a few things so far. I tried changing the size limit in ldap.conf and slapd.conf to arbitrarily large numbers, as well as "unlimited" and "-1" which I saw were potential keywords you could use on various sites. That did not work.

Then, I attempted to use paged results. This was done use python ldap, and also did not work. I can go through the pages of results that I get back, but again it will not give me a total of more than 500 results. For instance, I did pages with 10 entries, pages with 100 entries, and pages with 500 entries. For the 10 entry pages, I could get 50 pages before it crapped out. For 100, I got 5 pages. For 500, 1 page. 500 entries is the default limit for ldapsearch to return, but I really need to be able to get more than that.

Does anyone have some ideas on how to get rid of that low maximum value?

Answer (score 5):

`sizelimit` in the `slapd.conf` file is the maximum number of entries that can be returned by the openldap server irrespective of whether paged search results are used or not. This value is probably set as 500 on your server. Also, on a side note you can set the `page-size` using `ldapsearch` command by using `-Epr`.

Comment: When using 'cn=config' the key attribute is 'olcSizeLimit'